# Why does Mavensmate on Sublime Text 3 not seem to be autosaving any Apex class

Tags: mavensmate, compile

Today, I find I have to Ctrl-S then Ctrl-Shift-S a class file to make it compile using Mavensmate on Sublime Text 3. I feel sure that only a single keystroke was needed before.

Am I correct? Is there a way to reinstate the behavior?

Comment: In the settings, have you got:
//if true, MavensMate will capture the save file operation and compile to the Salesforce.com server automatically 
"mm_compile_on_save" : true ?

Comment: You should post that as an answer!

Comment: I checked. I have "mm_compile_on_save" : true in Default and User Settings and Project Settings are blank. But that's a good answer.

Comment: @Dizzley a good answer has to solve your specific problem. I have the same problem as you and I also have my settings with the compile on save activated, but I have to hit ctrl+shift+s. What's more confusing to me is that it just stopped working.

Comment: @pedro-otero Sadly, you are right. This answer does not solve my problem. It's definitely a valuable answer though and worth checking for anyone who reads the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away. No positive action was taken and I could not explain how or why the "compile on save" function returned.

Comment: the magic of package managers?

Comment: I had the same problem and realised that I had the class open in both Sublime and Dev Console and they were conflicting.  Closed both and re-opened in Sublime only and the compile on ctrl-s behaviour returned.  Can't say for sure that that was the problem but that's what I observed.

Comment: Having been through the compile loop 1000's of times. I can see that this would cause a similar problem. Thanks for the comment, @MikeA

Answer (score 4):

In MavensMate settings, make sure you have the following setting enabled:

```
//if true, MavensMate will capture the save file operation and compile to the Salesforce.com server automatically 
"mm_compile_on_save" : true
```

Comment: I do have "mm_compile_on_save" : true. However, no compilation takes place when I save a changed file. I still think you have a good answer.